# Troubleshoot why Tableau Action doesn't show one value

Tags: dictionary, filter, action, tableau-api

I created Tableau Dashboard Actions.

If no action is taken, all data is displayed, i.e.

[image]

And when I click the appropriate data point, the appropriate data displays in other sheets of the Dashboard - except one.

[image]

How to troubleshoot when only one datapoint doesn't work?

When I toggle through filter, i.e. dropdown, all values show.

But when I create action to **hover or select point in map**, the problem persists with one data source.

I know it's not a filtering issue.

I recreated the flat source file, and the entire Tableau program, but the problem still persists.

What else can I troubleshoot?

Location 2 is very close to other locations, if that matters, but the locations nearby also work

[image]

And when I remove Location 2 from the flat-file and re-load tableau, all points work.

So I'm trying to figure out

1. If I use Locations drop down as a filter, all locations work, and only the relevant points are plotted on the map
2. If I create action for hovering over point in map, all points work except Location 2

I re-added one of the datapoints, even re-named the address but it's still not working.

Comment: Take a look at what other filters you have on that worksheet. Remove the ones you don't need. Random clicking causes them to be added

Comment: @FirebladeDan You know, I was thinking this, but I couldn't find any, so now I'm recreating the data to see if there is a difference.

Comment: @FirebladeDan I recreated the whole tableau, and even the flat data file and the problem still persists. I'll update question.

Comment: @FirebladeDan I was troubleshooting this, and created proof of concept workbook and changed ATTR to Dimension, but for some reason the particular latitude and longitude isn't appearing. See followup question, which includes link to uploaded workbook, https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/LocalBusinessRatings/LocalBusinessRatings. The problem is with `Eat at Joes`. It doesn't appear on map, but when I select from drop-down, it is at same point as `Belfrance Chocolate`