# Tableau reacts poorly to latitude and longitude for one particular location

Tags: dictionary, latitude-longitude, tableau-api

I have been [troubleshooting this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339722/troubleshoot-why-tableau-action-doesnt-show-one-value) where I click on datapoint in geographic map and NOTHING appears. However, all other datepoints work as expected

Troubleshooting steps

1. I deleted and re-created the tableau map
2. I removed the offending datapoint, and all other datapoints worked
3. I renamed the address of the datapoint, same problem

But then, I changed the latitude and longitude of the data-point and it worked.

Now when I revert to the correct latitude and longitude of the data-point it doesn't work.

Why on Earth doesn't it work?

Is there a certain way I should format longitude and latitude? This is how I formatted it:

[image]

Please please please help. I've been working on this all day.

This is screenshot of it working, when I select location from drop-down

[image]

This is screenshot when I select data-point from map and it DOESN'T WORK.

Notice how data at the bottom is BLANK, as if nothing is selected.

[image]

But if I select any other data-point on map it works

[image]

#### Update

Proof of concept is [here](https://public.tableau.com/shared/XXGDBHXMQ?:display_count=yes),

Notice when you click on `Eat at Joes` on map, the data display is blank, but if you select `Eat at Joes` from dropdown, then it works

#### Another update

If I go to dashboard, do rectangular select, this is what I get

[image]

If I go to original map and do rectangular select, I get this. It says 64 marks, 1 row by 1 column

[image]

And if I use quick filter, select `Eat at Joes`, it displays the data, including the name `Eat at Joes`

[image]

But if I hover over or select 'Eat at Joes`on the map (not the drop-down), the name in the dashboard says`None`instead of`Eat at Joes`.

And this happens to **all** data points that I hover over.

[image]

I uploaded latest workbook [here](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/LocalBusinessRatings/LocalBusinessRatings)

#### Update after calculated field

I dragged Cal_Loc to Details and it is aggregate (I am unable to change to Dimension) and not appearing in drop-down of dashboard panel.

However on lower left corner of Maps screen, it says `5 marks` even though I see 4, which is still quite unsettling ...

[image]

Comment: Sohni, is there any chance you could publish your workbook somewhere? I have a few guesses as to what your problem might be, but without getting to look at the data/workbook, they can only be guesses. Maybe there's a way you could anonymize it? If not, I can just take some stabs at it.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see a screenshot of the dashboard action menu for the action in question, as well as a screenshot showing what fields are put where in the worksheet in question.

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise Ahhhhh, I will try to anonymize it somehow. As a quick fix, I slightly changed the latitude point, so now the location is 100 feet away from the building.

Comment: Ach, that's such a ridiculous thing for you to have to do, I just don't know how to diagnose the problem without more information.
So what's the lat/lng that seems to be the problem? You're saying that when you change the lat/lng for this point, and nothing but the lat/lng, then the problem disappears?

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise Yes. When I change lat/long it disappears. But this is band-aid approach. Some tableau maps consist of 2000 points, and this approach is simply not possible. Will get workbook at earliest.

Comment: Would you mind giving me the troublesome lat/lng pair (exactly as it appears in the data), and then two or three lat/lng pairs that aren't giving you trouble (again, exactly as they appear in the data)?

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise `Troublesome pair (Lat/Long): 40.694191/-73.985179`. Working pairs: 40.693463/-73.988245, 40.690885/-73.988553, 40.691713/-73.990935

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise I included link to workbook in original question, https://public.tableau.com/shared/XXGDBHXMQ?:display_count=yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.

The first is that you're using `ATTR()`. Instead of putting the fields of interest into Tooltip as attributes, put them into Detail as dimensions. Filtering on an attribute is tricky (that *'ll get you into all sorts of trouble). For filtering, dimensions are usually the way to go.

The second is that you have lat/lng in the map as dimensions. Try changing them to a measure. If your dimensions (Location, Type) can uniquely identify every point on the map (and now that you've made them dimensions and not attributes, they can), then you can have the lat/lng averaged.

Your title problem is a known issue with Tableau. They've acknowledged the problem for about two and a half years now, but there's no fix in sight. Behavior with putting dimensions in titles is very inconsistent (a quick search through the Tableau forums reveals a pretty shocking number of people with your exact issue). I couldn't find a solution to your problem, but here's a hacked together one specific to your situation.

Make a calculated field:

```
IIF(COUNTD([Location]) > 1, 'Multiple Locations', ATTR([Location]))
```

Then replace [Location] in your title with that field. It just checks to see how many locations are present in the partition. If there's just one, it uses `ATTR([Location])`, which we can safely assume will return the name of a single location and not a "*". Otherwise, it returns "Multiple Locations", which you can obviously adjust to fit your needs.

Comment: I tried this and uploaded. Now I have new problem. When I select all, `Eat at Joes` does not appear at all, i.e. there are 4 datapoints instead of 5. And when I specifically choose `Eat at Joes` from dashboard drop-down and hover over `Eat at Joes`, it still displays blank. I also noticed that when I select `All`, one datapoint says `Belfrance Chocolate`, but when I select `Eat at Joes` it displays datapoint at same location as `Belfrance Chocolate`.

Comment: I posted new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379686/tableau-dashboard-doesnt-display-name-when-clicking-on-map

Comment: I haven't given up on you, Sohni. Just haven't had time to really dig in. But I _definitely_ haven't given up on you.

Comment: You mentioned that there are only 4 data points instead of 5, but that's not the case on my end. Do a Rectangular Selection (click and drag) around all five points, and the command menu that pops up will show that you have 5 points selected.

Comment: @SohniMahiwal, I updated my answer with a new possible fix.

Comment: I changed them to measure(avg), but still only 4 points show. Also did rectangular select, and I deselected Analysis > Aggregate

Comment: Two of the points will be right on top of one another. When you did the rectangular select, in the bottom left corner of the screen, it should say something like "5 of 5 marks". Does it show that you selected five marks or four? When you use the quick filter to show only Eat At Joe's, then hover over Eat At Joe's, do you still have the problem where everything disappears? If these problems persist, could you please update the workbook on Tableau Public? I'm determined to get this...

Comment: @SohniMahiwal, I've updated the answer again. Also note that I removed the bit about not aggregating the lat/lng. That was a bad call on my end, sorry. Just use `AVG()`. Hope this one works for you!

Comment: Will check this out soon!

Comment: I created calculated field `Cal_Loc` and when I attempt to replace it with `Location` in dashboard, it doesn't appear in the Insert menu. I uploaded latest workbook. And four points still show instead of five :-( Seems that `Belfrance Chocolate` and `Eat at Joes` are at same point in map, but `Belfance Chocolate` shows

Comment: @SohniMahiwal, the title can only see fields that are in the worksheet, so you'll need to drag `Cal_Loc` into Detail on that worksheet. Are you sure there are only four marks? How many marks does it say are present in the bottom left corner? Two will really be right on top of each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89020/discussion-between-sohni-mahiwal-and-andrew-laprise).